# How to clean an array from empty objects in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

Afterwards an aggregation in `mongodb` I get this results:

```
[
  my_arr:[
    {
      id: ObjectId('618f7ef057c2923be10d1111')
      //other stuff
    },
    {},
    {},
  ]
]
```

Is there a way to remove the empty object directly in the aggregation? or it is necessary to do it server side? I get that after doing an unwind and a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new aggregation stage ( `$project`, `$set` or `$addFields`) with `$filter` like this:

```
{
  "$project": {
    "my_arr": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$my_arr",
        "as": "a",
        "cond": {
          "$ne": [
            "$$a",
            {}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This filter get only objects into the array where the object itself is not empty (i.e. is not `{}`)

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cmRIj4BZd0K)

Also [$set example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3EKMoqYx4EP) and [$addFields example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/npIVUt9F_wl)

Also, you can use `$$this` to refer the object instead of value from `as`. Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WAzxeb4RRvq)